# what is wrong with this jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant seem to figure this out. Something within this jquery code is breaking my site:

```
    $('.menu li').click(function() {
        nextslide = $(this).attr('id').replace('m_', '');

        if ($('#m_till').hasClass('active'))
            currentslide = 'till';
        else if ($('#m_receipts').hasClass('active'))
            currentslide = 'receipts';
        else
            currentslide = 'support';   

        slide_right(currentslide, nextslide);
    }
```

When I remove this code, my site works fine. So it has to be something within this function that is causing the problem.

Comment: Install FireBug, run this in FireFox, and see what error the console shows you.

Comment: Include your markup and give us some idea of what the problem you see is.

Comment: Do you have an error from firebug?

Comment: Do you get any script errors? Firebug for firefox is tool you will need if you are going to do web development. Chrome, IE(press f12) has built in tools and I would guess Safari and Opera has too.

Comment: You haven't declared those variables making them implicit global variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it looks like theres a `);` missing at the end

```
$('.menu li').click(function() {
        nextslide = $(this).attr('id').replace('m_', '');

        if ($('#m_till').hasClass('active'))
            currentslide = 'till';
        else if ($('#m_receipts').hasClass('active'))
            currentslide = 'receipts';
        else
            currentslide = 'support';   

        slide_right(currentslide, nextslide);
    });
```

Comment: As far as correcting blind issues is concerned, this would be my best-guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.menu li').click(function() {
    nextslide = $(this).attr('id').replace('m_', '');

    if ($('#m_till').hasClass('active'))
        currentslide = 'till';
    else if ($('#m_receipts').hasClass('active'))
        currentslide = 'receipts';
    else
        currentslide = 'support';   

    slide_right(currentslide, nextslide);
}

//close it
);
//close it
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do to troubleshoot any javascript is to assign the parts to variables, then check out the variables.

```
var a = $('.menu li');
a.click();
```

and more examples:

```
var a = $(this);
var b = a.attr('id');
var c = b.replace('m_', '');
```

It's likely you are referencing something that doesn't exist, assuming your syntax is correct.  Use Chrome developer tools or Firefox Firebug to break on that variable and check the value.